# Error wickrio_addon.node is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: node.js, docker

I've been to trying to get my hands off this by reinstalling node.js but keeps giving me same issues.

```
Error: \\?\C:\Users\iSel Media\Desktop\wickrio_web_interface-master\node_modules\wickrio_addon\wickrio_addon.node is not a valid Win32 application.
\\?\C:\Users\iSel Media\Desktop\wickrio_web_interface-master\node_modules\wickrio_addon\wickrio_addon.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1187:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\iSel Media\Desktop\wickrio_web_interface-master\node_modules\wickrio-bot-api\src\WickrIOBot.js:1:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

Comment: This error message has to do with the installation of the wickrio addons and it appears that they are not properly installed.  It does not have to do with the nodejs installation.  I would suggest reinstalling the wickrio components and pay particular attention to any errors you see in their installation.

Comment: There's not enough here for us to know what the specific problem is, just to advise what your next step in troubleshooting would be.